# In how many ways can six people be seated at a round table if two particular people will not sit in adjacent seats?

Tags: combinatorics

### My problem

6 friends want to eat all together around a circular table but there is a problem because two of them are divorced and don't want to eat side by side. (In this case, there is only the relative position that counts.)

### My try

#### If they were not divorced

It's a permutation, so there is $6!$ possibilities if the relative position doesn't count, so there are always $6$ positions that are the same (if we only shift the places).
So there is,
$$\frac{6!}{6} = 5! = 120 \text{ possibilities}$$

#### They are divorced

At first I thought that because there is only the relative position that counts, the two divorced can be only one time left of the other and one time right of the other, but with more thinking, I don't think it's coherent.

Can somone help me please with a tip ?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: So there's two pairs where the people within each pair can't be paired (i.e. sit next to each other).

Comment: I don't understand why only rotation counts but not reflection.

Comment: The two divorced eaters are $A$ and $B$. Fix the place of $A$ at the round table. Now check the possibilities for $B$ first. From the five remained places two are forbidden...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call that ex-couple Albert & Beatrice and look at arrangments counterclockwise from Albert, calling Albert's position number 1. If we look at all possible seating aarrangements of Beatrice and the others in positions 2,..,6, there would be 5!=120 possibilities. Of these there would be 4!=24 arrangemtnts with Beatrice in position 2and another 24 arrangements with Beatrice in position 6. So altogether, the number of acceptable arrangements would be 120-24-24=72.

Answer (score 1):

Let Ann and Bob be the two persons that cannot be seated side by side.

There are $\frac{6!}6=5!=120$ ways to arrange $6$ people on a round table. You have to exclude those where A sits next to B.

To compute these, think A and B as one single person, so the clockwise arrangements ...AB... are $\frac{5!}5=4!=24$. But you have to double that since you also need to exclude the symmetric arrangements ...BA... .

Thus the total is $120-2\cdot24=72$.

Answer (score 0):

Albert in position 1 forbids positions 6 and 2 for Beatrice, who can seat on 3 positions. It leaves 4 positions for the others. Therefore if Albert sits in 1 there are 3x24 possibilities. Finally, since Albert can actually sits on 6 positions, the answer is

```
  6x3x24=432< 6!=720
```

Comment: Albert's position is irrelevant because rotations leave the configuration of the sittings unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Consider the other $4$ people who have no trouble sitting anywhere. The number of ways you can arrange these $4$ people in a circle is exactly $\frac{4!}{4} = 3!$

Now consider all the places between these $4$ people,there are $4$ such places. You can place the troublesome two fellows in any of these places. So for each of the $3!$ ways you can arrange the $4$ people with no trouble you can seat the $2$ troublesome fellows in $4C2 \times 2!$ ways.

So your answer would be $3! \times 4C2 \times 2! =72$

Comment: Very funny, all the answers are giving different results.

Comment: $3! \times 4C2 \times 2! = 72$ , this is the correct answer. In fact this was one of my tutorial questions and my TA confirmed it.